# Cannot create git repository using Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

I have created a project that I would like to push to my GitHub account. Unfortunately, I did not create a GitHub repository when creating the project. When I attempt to create a repository using Xcode by following the path of Source Control -> Create Git Repository, Xcode displays a popup stating that "all projects are already under source control." This is not the case and the project is not in my GitHub account. Here is a screen cap of the error. What am I missing?

[image: Source Code Error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project **is** under source control.. As you can see the files marked with letters "R" (for Renamed) and "M" (for Modified) and "A" (for Added)

By default Xcode creates a local git repository for new project unless you uncheck that option

Check [this](https://medium.com/xcblog/the-marriage-of-github-and-xcode-9-at-wwdc-821b78eb6797) out

> Xcode will automatically add it under source control.

You just need to define a remote. Right click on the repository (from the git pane) and tap on "Add existing remote.."

Comment: I didn't know that. So how can I push this to my GitHub account? I have a repository created for the project in my account. Any attempts to commit or push are not applied in GitHub.

Comment: Sure you can, just define a "remote" for your git local repository... Find in Xcode how to do it

Comment: Yup, that was the step I was missing. I'm a noob and I appreciate the help. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewTuzson Have it worked? I tried 
Editor > Create Remote on GitHub

Repository creation failed. :(

Comment: You first need to create a remote in the Show Source Control Navigator section of the navigator. Right click on remotes and create a new remote. Once that is complete, you should be able to push and commit your changes.